# assign unallocated space to /?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, cuda

I was installing CUDA on my computer and got an alert that "remaining space not enough". So I checked my partition using `gparted` and found out that my partition scheme while installing Ubuntu 18.04 in the first place was just completely messed up. I have too much space on `/media` but only about 20GB for `/`.(as suggested by tutorials actually)

But, now I wanna assign some free space to my `/`, since they are under the different partition, is there a possible way to do this besides booting from a live system? My last installation had too many problems so I would do anything to avoid going through it again.

This is my partition reference:

[image: partition]

Comment: Ubuntu documentation says a minimum of 25gb (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).  If the tutorials are official sources, can you please say where. The more software you add, the more space you need, plus if you upgrade you need space for donwload plus upgraded packages. If they were unofficial (youtube tutorials), you'll have to take it up with the creator.  the `ext` fs (filesystem) does not allow 'hot' (whilst mounted) changes, if you wanted to have this option you needed to allow for it on fs creation.  Alternatives are difficult & prone to error if unskilled

Comment: I have successfully increased my root partition by entering with live session. It took too much time to process when I clicked green tick mark in GParted. I took my data backup before doing it.

Comment: You can only add unallocated space to an adjacent partition. In your case, you should backup all your data, and boot from a Live USB (this should be easy, if you're careful), then add `Unallocated Space` to `/dev/sda4` (the extended partition), then move `linux-swap` to the other side of `Unallocated Space`, and finally, merge `Unallocated Space` with `/dev/sda6`